# Power bi Limited relationship Issue

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have data that is coming from Live connection from SSAS and another one coming from Share point. I created relationship between the two tables but is is giving me Limited Relationship. Does anyone know i can fix it?
Thanks

Comment: The happens when using DirectQuery/Live connection (ie composite models). Can't be fixed. See [Regular and limited relationships in Power BI](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/strong-and-weak-relationships-in-power-bi/)